# Angular Reactive forms - Value from Async call not updating form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm retrieving information for vehicle data from my API. And then validate the fields.

My ts file looks like this:

```
vehicleDetails = new CartellInfo();

ngOnInit() {
    this.claimForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        plateNumber: [ this.vehicleDetails.registration, [Validators.required] ],
        vehicleManufacturer: [ this.vehicleDetails.make, [Validators.required] ],
        vehicleModel: [ this.vehicleDetails.model, [Validators.required] ],
        vehicleRange: [ this.vehicleDetails.description, [Validators.required] ],
        chasisNumber: [ this.vehicleDetails.chassisNumber, [Validators.required] ],
        fuelType: [ this.vehicleDetails.fuelType, [Validators.required] ],
        dateFirstRegistered: [ this.vehicleDetails.firstRegistrationDate, [Validators.required] ],
        engineCapacity: [ this.vehicleDetails.engineCapacity, [Validators.required] ]
    });
}

findVehicle() {
    if (this.registration !== null) {

        this.cartellService.findVehicle(this.registration)
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            this.vehicleFound = true;
            this.vehicleDetails = res;
        });
    }
}
```

And the HTML for one of them looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="findVehicle()">FIND VEHICLE</button>

<input class="form-control"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-form-field-readonly': vehicleDetails.model || available }"
    [readonly]="vehicleDetails.model || available"
    name="vehicleModel"
    [formControl]="f.vehicleModel"
>
<mat-error *ngIf="submitted && f.vehicleModel.hasError('required')">
    Vehicle model is <strong>required</strong>
</mat-error>
```

But my input doesn't reflect data coming from the API. If you look code behind, the value is there, but it's not showing up.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here you are assigning ```kilometers: [ '', [Validators.required] ]``` empty values to kilometers, then how will you get the value in form field??

Comment: I updated it to use another input... the kilometers one actually has another logic behind. The other one are not visible! So forget about the kilometers one. Gonna delete it.

Comment: Use `tap` to construct the `FormGroup` after the API call returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set form after you receive the response.

```
this.cartellService.findVehicle(this.registration)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.vehicleFound = true;
      this.vehicleDetails = res;
      this.claimForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          plateNumber: [ this.vehicleDetails.registration, [Validators.required] ],
          vehicleManufacturer: [ this.vehicleDetails.make, [Validators.required] ],
          vehicleModel: [ this.vehicleDetails.model, [Validators.required] ],
          vehicleRange: [ this.vehicleDetails.description, [Validators.required] ],
          chasisNumber: [ this.vehicleDetails.chassisNumber, [Validators.required] ],
          fuelType: [ this.vehicleDetails.fuelType, [Validators.required] ],
          dateFirstRegistered: [ this.vehicleDetails.firstRegistrationDate, [Validators.required] ],
          engineCapacity: [ this.vehicleDetails.engineCapacity, [Validators.required] ]
      });
    });
```

Or you can set the form value with the response.

```
this.cartellService.findVehicle(this.registration)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.vehicleFound = true;
      this.vehicleDetails = res;
      this.claimForm.setValue({
          plateNumber: this.vehicleDetails.registration,
          vehicleManufacturer: this.vehicleDetails.make,
          vehicleModel: this.vehicleDetails.model,
          vehicleRange: this.vehicleDetails.description,
          chasisNumber: this.vehicleDetails.chassisNumber,
          fuelType: this.vehicleDetails.fuelType,
          dateFirstRegistered: this.vehicleDetails.firstRegistrationDate,
          engineCapacity: this.vehicleDetails.engineCapacity
      });
    });
```

Comment: So that's more or less what I needed to do! 
I just updated the values for each form (instead of creating them, this is not happening on onInit, but on a button click). So just changing the values will work!

Comment: Just a suggestion, I believe template-driven form would be an good approach in your case as you can use the good old friend `ngModel` to bind values, if you prefer not to update manually.

Comment: @Shravan I will give it a try as it sounds like a better solution for me... Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was necessary to run the change detection manually in the callback.
This can be achieved by importing

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

and running

```
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```